# How to run discorn.py in a loop without closing the client at the end of each loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**What I need**

I need a function that will run in a loop and send messages to discord channel

**Problem**

I have a function that sends messages to a discord channel

```
def send_discord(msg):

    token = '0000000000000000000000000000000000'

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():    
        channel = client.get_channel(000000000000000)
        await channel.send(msg)
        
        await client.close()

    client.run(token)
```

I need to run this function in a loop to get messages info and send it
At the moment I need to open the discord client each time before sending a messge. And then close it after the message is sent. This takes lots of time

If I don't close the client after sending the message - the program stops.

**Question**

How can I run my function in a loop without opening and closing it each time?

Comment: Any reason you don't use a `task loop` to do this? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use webhooks?

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook
    
def send_discord(msg)
    webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='your webhook url', content=msg)
    webhook.execute() # Send a message using the webhook
```

You can make a webhook just for a specific channel and use it to send messages. It doesn't need to login to discord and just needs the webhook url.

Read more about the module here:
https://github.com/lovvskillz/python-discord-webhook

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [`discord.on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event!

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if ctx.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID: return
    # YOUR FUNCTION HERE
```